# Unexpected start of structured construct in definition. Expected '=' or other token F#

Tags: f#

I am trying to make a vector library with a hidden Vector type but i get the following error:

> Unexpected start of structured construct in definition. Expected '='
> or other token

I am trying to learn how modules work, and i took this example from a book where I copied exactly as given and still got this error.

[Screenshot with code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXW1U.png)

The given errors are :

```
`error FS0039: The value or constructor 'make' is not defined.

error FS0010: Unexpected start of structured construct in definition. Expected '=' or other token.
```

`

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), specifically, do not paste screenshots but instead provide the code. This makes it easier to reproduce the problem and provide an answer.

Answer (score 4):

F# has 2 sintaxis for `module`

Top level module without the `=`

```
module Vector

type Vector = V of float * float
let (~-.) (V(x, y)) = V(-x, -y)
```

Which acts as a `namespace` and `module` declaration in one.
Components can be indented at the same level as the `module Vector`, like in
the book example. F# interactive doesn't recognize this form, so you need to use the other form:

Sub modules with the `=`:

```
module Vector =

    type Vector = V of float * float
    let (~-.) (V(x, y)) = V(-x, -y)
```

Which require its components to be indented further inside.

Here is the documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/modules

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the first `type Vector` then just indent the module:

```
module Vector =

    type Vector = V of float*float
    let (~-.) (V(x,y)) = V(-x, -y)
    let make (x, y) = V(x, y)

    let a = make(1.0, 2.0) // V (1.0, 2.0)
```